# cordova.file.getExternalCacheDir() returns null in android 11 emulator

Tags: android-studio, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-11

I am trying to test my hybrid app with android 11 emulator provided in android studio. But, on requesting `filesystem`, the `cordova` file plugin is returning `null` values in `externalRootDirectory`. In my code, I have checked this value to initialize app folder, and now it is not working.

I have used `cordova` android 8.0.0, `cordova` file plugin 6.0.2, and file transfer 1.7.0.

Do anyone have same issue while testing in android 11?

**Edit:**

On debugging in cordova file plugins, we find that cordova does not provide path to external cache directory in android 11 emulator. Anyone aware of this change?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with Android 11 emulators, trying to run a native app

Comment: I have the same behavior. Working with an Android 10 emulator until they fix this.